# Python Class from module, is lost after exit from function - even with global used

Tags: python-3.x, class, global-variables

here's my simplified code:

Module1.py

```
class cl1():
def __init__(self, address='1.1.1.1'):
    try:
        some code
    except:
        print(' fail ')
def f1(self):
    do sth1
    .
    .
    .
def f10(self):
   do sth10
```

Module wnd.py

```
from Module1 import class1

global glob_var 
glob_var=None
input = '8.8.8.0'   

def fo_1(input):
    global glob_var
    glob_var=cl1(input)
    glob_var.f1() #Here code is working 

def fo_2(input):
    global glob_var
    glob_var.f5() #Here code is not working
```

How it works: 
In module `wnd.py`, function `fo_1` and `fo_2` is called externally by button. `fo_1` is working fine, but when i call `fo_2` i got error ***AttributeError***: `int` object has no attribute `f5`.

**Debuging:** when i'm in `fo_1` i see that class is assigned to `glob_var`, but when calling `fo_2` `glob_var` is `0`. I don't understand why `glob_var` is lost after exit from `fo_1`. Additionally when i make `glob_var=class1(input)` outside the functions, code is working fine and both functions works fine. Do you know the reason of such behavior (why `fo_2` can't see global variable as i expected)?

Comment: A bit confused: is this `global_var` or `glob_var`? can it be spelling?

Comment: yes, good catch, just corrected. Variable name is glob_var